# Doctrine entity and Zf2 module dependancy

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, circular-dependency

I have 2 modules.

Config with ConfigEntity and 
Reporting with ReportingEntity

Those entities have a oneToManyRelation:

```
class Config
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reportings = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Reporting\Entity\ConfigReporting",
     * mappedBy="config", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $reportings;
}

class ConfigReporting
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Config\Entity\Config", inversedBy="reportings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="config", referencedColumnName="idConfig", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $config;

}
```

My module Reporting **depends** on Config's module to work. But with this doctrine's mapping, do i have a circular dependancy ?

If yes, do i have to declare the Reporting entity into Config module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be a problem.

Did you try to setup the classes like you show? Did you run into any problems?

### UPDATE

You can change your mapping to Unidirectional. Then you can turn of your Reporting module without problems. The disadvantage is that your `Config` entity will not be aware of the association...

```
class Config
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

class ConfigReporting
{
    /**
     * Unidirectional mapping owning side.
     *
     * @var int|null
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Config\Entity\Config")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="config", referencedColumnName="idConfig", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $config;
}
```

Comment: i had no problem at all when i setup classes like this, but if I choose to deactivate Reporting, Mapping of Config can't work. Then Config need Reporting, and Reporting need Config, you see my point ?

Comment: I understand your problem now, I will update my answer.

Comment: You can also read [Keeping your Modules independent](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html#keeping-your-modules-independent) chapter of Doctrine2. Maybe it can help you too?

Comment: Yeah your link help me a lot, but I don't understand the last part. In zf2 context where i configure this...?

Comment: @Hooli I guess that is up to you :)

Comment: @copynpaste thanks for your help, your earned points for this